# hay que pagar por usar docker ce ?. investigué en muchas partes pero no pude encontrar información

Tags: docker

esperando tengan un buen día/noche. Quisiera saber si puedo usar en producción docker ce  y con ello cobrar por usar mis servicios en la nube  ?

saludos a todos!

Comment: Docker CE es gratis.

Answer (score 0):

no, es totalmente gratuito, en https://aws.amazon.com/es/docker/ puedes ver la respuesta a tu pregunta: "*... La versión Docker Community Edition (CE) es de uso gratuito para todos. Esta versión de Docker es de código abierto y se puede usar en diversas plataformas, incluidas Windows, Mac y Linux. Puede instalar Docker CE en su ordenador o en una instancia de máquina virtual de Amazon EC2 ...*"